# Why is the Axiom of Well-ordered Choice not strong enough to prove Zorn's Lemma?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, foundations, well-orders

This is based on this question: [How strong is the axiom of well-ordered choice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140508/how-strong-is-the-axiom-of-well-ordered-choice)

The "axiom of well-ordered choice" says that any *transfinitely-indexed* family of sets has a choice function. The individual sets within the family need not be well-ordered, but the family must be. We also assume the family is set-sized, so that the indices only go up to some ordinal.

I was going to give a direct example of where I'm stuck with Zorn's lemma, but it seems like it's easier to go with the Well-Ordering Principle (which indirectly uses Zorn's lemma anyway).

The usual proof sketch is, you begin with some set $S$ and select an initial element $e_0$. Then, via transfinite recursion you select an element $e_\alpha$ for any ordinal $\alpha$ from the set $S \setminus \{e_n: n < \alpha\}$. This process must "run out" of elements to select at some point, or else $S$ would have as many elements as ordinals, which it can't because it's a set. The resulting sequence of $e_n$'s is a well-ordering on $S$.

Of course, one cannot simply "select" elements from this family of sets without something like the axiom of choice. With AC, we can define a choice function on the power set $P(S) \setminus \{\}$, so that we know that we are always able to choose an element. This can be thought of as a choice function on a "partially ordered family of sets."

However, we don't really *need* a choice function on all of $P(S) \setminus \{\}$ for this. We only need a choice function on a particular transfinitely-indexed family of subsets of $S$ - each of which contains one less element than the last, or is equal to the intersection of all previous subsets at a limit ordinal. So rather than a partially ordered family of sets, we get a well-ordered family of sets. Since this is transfinitely-indexed, why can't we use the "well-ordered AC" here?

The same basic question applies to Zorn's lemma above, although I thought the above example was clearer. You begin with an initial element in some poset which has upper bounds for every chain, then transfinitely choose a sequence of larger elements until you run out. This is typically formalized by mapping a chain to the set of its larger elements, and then using AC to create a choice function selecting exactly one larger element from each set. This is equivalent to using AC on a partially ordered family of sets, however we only need to use it on one particular chain, which is a well-ordered family of sets. Why can't we use the well-ordered AC here?

Basically, why isn't the well-ordered AC equivalent to the usual AC?

Comment: Well. Not every set can be well-ordered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed reduce AC to "AC for well-ordered *processes*" - however, AWC is "AC for well-ordered *index sets*," which is quite a different (and weaker) thing.

To see the difference, let's follow your idea for a *two-element set* $X=\{a,b\}$. Our first "stage" is: **pick an element $e_0$ from the set $X$**. Our second stage is: **pick an element $e_1$ from the set $X\setminus\{e_1\}$**.

On the face of it this may seem like we've used the (trivial) axiom of choice for two sets. However, we haven't really done that, since *our second set depended on our first choice*. For AWC you need to set forth *ahead of time* a well-ordered set of choices you want to make. But you need a bit more than that to prove WOP: basically, you need "well-ordered [**dependent** choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice)" rather than simply well-ordered choice. And the problem is that while the set of "stages" in your construction is well-orderable, the set of sets you might need to choose from *isn't* (at least, a priori), and so mere AWC won't help you here.

Incidentally, note that DC - which is basically "dependent choice for $\omega$-many stages" - is indeed strictly stronger than the axiom of countable choice, which is the "index-set-instead-of-stages" version. So there's a pattern here.

Comment: Aha! Ok, so "well-ordered dependent choice" is equivalent to AC, but this is weaker. Thank you!