# How to construct a sequence inductively in set theory?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, set-theory

I would like to construct a sequence $\{a_n\}$ inductively in set theory.

> (1) I can choose $a_1$ from $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> (2) If I have chosen $a_i$ ($i \ge 1$), then there exists a set $S_i (\subset \mathbb{R})$ which **depends on $a_i$** and I can choose $a_{i+1}$ from $S_i$.

The tricky part that every $S_i$ is dependent on $a_i$. If $S_i$ doesn't depend on $a_i$, we have a choice function. However, in this case, how can we know there is a choice function which guarantees the existence of the sequence $\{a_n\}$? (The source of this question is in the following.)

[image]

Comment: If you know $S_i \subseteq \Bbb N$, you don't even need choice to guarantee the existence of a choice function.  Just use the least element of $S_i$.

Comment: @RobertShore Ah, sorry. The original statement was a little more complicated. So, I think I need to change $S_i \subset \mathbb{N}$ to $S_i \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How is $S_i$ defined from $a_i$.  Presumably it is defined in such a way that allows choices.  In your example you are that $q$ is a limit point of $E*$ which, by definition for each $S_i$ a neghborhoid of $a_i$ *does* mean points exist and you *do* have a choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NOTE: the first two parts of the answer address the original version of the problem, where $\mathbb{R}$ was replaced with $\mathbb{N}$. There's still interesting material there, so I'm leaving those parts, but for the question as edited see the final section.*

---

Generalizing a bit, what you have is a **next option function** $$F: \mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$$ sending a given sequence $(a_1,...,a_n)$ to the set of "allowed next numbers" *(and let's say for simplicity that when $(a_1,...,a_n)$ itself is illegal we have $F((a_1,...,a_n))=\mathbb{N}$ - nothing is less legal that things already are)*.

Robert Shore's comment makes a key observation: since we're always picking from a well-ordered set (namely, $\mathbb{N}$) we can make our choices ahead of time: letting $$G:\mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}: (a_1,...,a_n)\mapsto \min(F((a_1,...,a_n))),$$ we have that $G((a_1,...,a_n))$ is always a "legal next choice" whenever $(a_1,...,a_n)$ is a "legal sequence so far."

---

That gets rid of the choicey flavor, and reveals the actual content: **recursion**. We want to define the sequence

- $a_1=G(\langle\rangle)$,
- $a_{n+1}=G(\langle a_1,..., a_n\rangle)$,

but that isn't an "all at once" definition and might feel weird at first.

This is where the **recursion theorem** kicks in: this is a result in set theory which says that we can in fact make sense of "definitions" like this. A special case of it (which is enough for your purposes here) is [given at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem); its more general form is the following:

> **(Almost-fully-general recursion theorem)** Suppose $\alpha$ is an ordinal, $X$ is a set, and $$I: X^{<\alpha}\rightarrow X$$ is a function. Then there is a unique $$f: \alpha\rightarrow X$$ (more intuitively, $f=(a_i)_{i\in\alpha}$ with each $a_i$ in $X$) such that for all $\beta<\alpha$ we have $$f(\beta)=I(f\upharpoonright\beta).$$

*As the title indicates, we can generalize a bit further ... but meh. Also, be careful not to confuse this with the [recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem) in computability theory or the [master/recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) in theoretical computer science and combinatorics.*

Here $I$ is our "iterator" telling us what to add to our "sequence-so-far," and $f$ is the "completed sequence" we want.

The axiom(s) which makes the recursion theorem work is the axiom (scheme) of [**replacement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement). This is in many ways *more powerful* than choice, e.g. in terms of [consistency strength](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#SecIncThe): ZFC is consistent if ZF is, but ZF proves the consistency of Z (= ZF without replacement) and so in principle ZF could be inconsistent even if Z is consistent.

Indeed, set theory without replacement is an incredibly finicky thing, as a quick glance at [this](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/maclane.pdf) will indicate.

---

Going back to the choice issue, what happens if we replace $\mathbb{N}$ with some more complicated set $X$, so that the "least element" trick need not apply?

In this case we're in the realm of [**dependent choice**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) principles; these are strictly weaker than choice, but still not provable from ZF alone. The usual axiom of dependent choice, DC, handles the case when we want to make $\omega$-many choices, but we also have stronger dependent choice axioms for "longer" processes, and there are [some subtleties](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3141506/28111) around these.

That said, we often *can* get away without choice by being a bit clever. This is along the lines of Robert Shore's original comment: although a choice function for arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ need not exist without choice, the particular situation we're looking at may admit one. This is often the case in topology, at least as concerns "simple" properties of "nice" spaces - for example, it's often enough to pick *rational* numbers instead of *real* numbers, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is (provably in ZF) well-orderable.

Comment: Thank you, but I made a mistake. The original statement was a little more complicated. So, I think I need to change $S_i \subset \mathbb{N}$ to $S_i \subset \mathbb{R}$. I will add to my original post the source of my question.

Comment: @withgrace1040 See my edit.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, can I ask what $\mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}$ means? Sorry for the lack of knowledge.

Comment: @withgrace1040 It's the set of finite sequences of natural numbers.

Comment: @withgrace1040 Incidentally, in the passage you quote you're choosing the $n_i$s, and these are *indices for* elements of the sequence, that is, they're natural numbers. So in fact we don't need the a priori heavier machinery of picking real numbers.

Comment: Yes, but $n_i$ depends on $x$, which is from the metric space $X$.

Comment: @withgrace1040 First of all, only one $\delta$ is needed, so that's just one choice; that doesn't involve AC. But even that is unnecessary, since $\delta$ is defined outright in terms of $n_1$ which itself was specifically defined. There really is no choice going on here.

Comment: @withgrace1040 Here's a version of the same argument which might be easier to parse. Suppose we have $(p_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $q$ fixed. Let $n_1=1$ and, having defined $n_i$, let $n_{i+1}$ be the smallest $m>n_i$ such that $d(p_m, q)<{1\over 2}\cdot d(p_{n_i}, q)$. Basically, "walk along our sequence towards $q$ using the greedy algorithm." It's then straightforward to show that this sequence is well-defined (without AC) and that the corresponding subsequence $(p_{n_i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $q$. *This is just a repackaging of the argument you're looking at, but perhaps clearer.*

Comment: I have a question. Here, we "inductively" construct a sequence. We know the existence of $a_i$. However, we didn't use "induction" on constructing this sequence right?

Comment: @withgrace1040 This is actually a pet peeve of mine. (Transfinite) induction is a *proof method*, while the definition style being used here is definition by *recursion* - we prove by induction but define by recursion. They are related, though: the proof that definition by recursion works (= the recursion theorem above) relies on (transfinite) induction. So "under the hood" induction is indeed being used, to show that definitions by recursion make sense, but "blackboxing" it no induction is used in the definition of the sequence itself.

Comment: Could you explain how this kind of definition by recursion works in set theory? The reason why I am asking this is that a sequence is a function and a function is a subset of a larger set $\mathbb{N} \times X$. Shouldn't we have the existence of this larger set, first?

Comment: @withgrace1040 Sure, one basic result in set theory is that "$A\times B$ exists whenever $A,B$ exists," and this doesn't need choice (or replacement for that matter). Stuff like that is more basic than definition by recursion, though, so when summarizing the situation I (and most others) ignore it to focus on the harder stuff.

Comment: But this is going a bit far afield from the original question - you should look at a set theory book's presentation, or (more easily but less completely) at some of the existing MSE questions on recursion in set theory, or ask a new one if you can't find one that resolves things.

Comment: Oh, I know that. I didn't mean it. I am confused about what I am confused. Let me think. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, okay. Let me summarize my question. I know we can 'heuristically' construct a sequence by recursion and we know the existence of $a_i$ in set theory. 

However, in set theory, a sequence is a subset of $\mathbb{N} \times X$. More specifically, using a set builder notation, $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{N} \times X | \cdots\}$. How can we fill $\cdots$ part, if the sequence is defined by recursion?

Comment: @withgrace1040 This is exactly what you should look at the proof of the recursion theorem to see. (You're absolutely right that it's not trivial!)

Comment: Ah, is there "the recursion theorem" in set theory??? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @withgrace1040 Yes, per my answer (look at the middle part - specifically, the yellowish box). I've edited to make it stand out more.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for your help! I was really interested in set theory and mathematical logic, but now I am studying analysis. While studying analysis, some issues related to set theory sometimes occur (personally). I haven't met or talked to a person who specializes in set theory and mathematical logic!

Comment: @withgrace1040 Glad to help - and there's a bunch of us here at MSE who specialize in those. :)

Comment: I envy you guys. Since there were no departments or professors who specialize in those in Korea, which I am from, I ended up choosing analysis, but I am still drawn by those areas!

Comment: Just one last question. Can I ask why definition by recursion or (transfinite) induction is a pet peeve of yours? Just curious. :)

Comment: @withgrace1040 There are situations where drawing the distinction is important mathematically. They don't crop up really outside logic, but given that that's where I work, I use the distinction fairly frequently.

Comment: Thank you for answering me! By the way, in my third comment to your answer post, I changed $\delta$ to $x$ because I wrote it wrong. However, you answered so quickly and I didn't have time to mention it. 

In this case, $x$ has to be picked for every $n_i$ while only one $\delta$, so we need the heavy machinery, but still not AC?